# What is the critical temperature for a BKT transition in the 2D quantum XY model with $S=1$ (not $S=1/2$)?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, topological-phase, spin-models, critical-phenomena

What is the critical temperature for a BKT transition in the 2D quantum XY model with $S=1$ (not $S=1/2$)?  For instance, the classical XY model has KTc/J = 0.898 and the quantum XY model with S=1/2 has KTc/J = .350.

Comment: Did you ever learn what the critical temperature was?